# Symfony: a way to show/hide list rows in action?

Tags: symfony1, action, generator, yaml, backend

i try to make set of actions that work similar to Index action, but they show filtered data (some kind of readymade reports).

So far I figured out something like this::

```
public function executeReport(sfWebRequest $request)
{ 
  $this->setFilters(array('field'=>'value'));

  $this->forward($this->getModuleName(), 'index');
}
```

but I also want to modify the set of columns.

Default set is stored in generator.yml

```
generator:
  param:
    config:
      list:
        display: [field1, field2, field3]
```

is there any way to set only field2 and field3 visible inside `executeReport()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override your generator configuration in module/lib/moduleGeneratorConfiguration.class.php:

The method that is used to fetch the fields is this:

```
public function getListDisplay()
{
  return array('field2','field3');
}
```

I've not tested it, but you should be able to override that with different values like this:

```
public function getListDisplay()
{
  return sfConfig::get('app_my_columns');
}
```

Comment: getListDisplay() works. but now how to set columns depending on action?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your template ReportSuccess.php with only the fields that you need.

Comment: I'd have to modify/override some partials too. I'm trying to avoid that. @Arend gave better solution

Answer (score 0):

maybe i'm wrong but if you hide attributes you are not hiding any row, you'll be hiding columns. To hide/show rows you can do it on the template file with an structure similar to this:

```
foreach($row_you_can_show as $row){
    if(you_want_to_show($row)){
         echo "<tr>...</tr>";
    }
}
```

If you want to control it dynamically you can do it with a javascript function, but is more complicated....

good luck